# Pass a functional component as argument, then use it in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I have a pair of functional components and want to pass one in as an argument to the other as shown below:

```
const compA = () => ( <div> Hello World! </div>);

const compB = (AnotherComp) => ( <AnotherComp />);

compB(compA);
```

The above snippet is a dumbed-down version of what I'm after, as each component has its own set of React hooks.

Google-fu turned up many guides on Higher-Order Components, but most address the difference between HOC and react hooks, or for getting props from a class component into a functional sub-component.

Is there a way to use Higher-order *functional* components, as shown above?

Comment: From the Higher-Order Components point of view, there's no difference from class based or function based.

Comment: You can just return a function component as you do with class ones. If you need to pass refs, use React.forwardRef. Check out the example here - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#displaying-a-custom-name-in-devtools

Comment: What isn't working here? This seems like valid React code: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-feather-59iuk

Comment: Your example seems like valid code: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-butterfly-crh6i. It might be worth clarifying the question if you're looking for some further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question, but it seems to me that for something to be considered higher order, you need a function to return a function, as in `makeBlue`, below.

```
const Button = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <button {...props}>{children}</button>
);

const makeBlue = (Component) => (props) =>
  <Component style={{ background: "blue" }} {...props} />;

const BlueButton = makeBlue(Button);
```

Yes, they work with functional components.